# python float format with variable precision based on float value

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision

I hope the title will not put people off, cause this is - as far as i can tell - NOT a duplicate.

situation: i have a number 0 .. x .. 1, which can be very small, so 1 >> n (e.g. 0.00001321).

problem: i want to print this number using 4 *significant* decimal places, so printing 0.00001 with precison "4" would be "0.0000". what i *want* is "0.00001321". same, if the number is "0.3" i want to print "0.3000".

examples:

```
value                      string representation
v = 0.00001231231231       format_v(v) == "0.00001231"
v = 0.00012312312312       format_v(v) == "0.0001231"
v = 0.00123123123123       format_v(v) == "0.001231"
v = 0.01231231231231       format_v(v) == "0.01231"
v = 0.12312312312312       format_v(v) == "0.1231"

def format_v(v):
   # that's the big question ...
   pass
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: flypenguin, If `v` was 0.000099996, how shoud that print? `"0.00010000"`?  (Case where rounding to 4 significant digits rounds to 5)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it should print "0.00009996" - _dynamic_ precision ;) . the 4 most significant digits should be printed.

Comment: @flypenguin The value is  0.000099996 with 4 nines and a six, not 0.00009996 with 3 nines.  As _text_, that rounds to "0.00010000".  Or are you looking for "0.0001000", with 1 less zero.  That is not so easy to do well.

Comment: Formatting with format specifier `#.4g` already gets you the right number of significant digits. If you want to avoid use of scientific notation, you can pass through the `Decimal` type to reformat. For example, `format(Decimal(format(0.00001231231231, '#.4g')), 'f')` gives `'0.00001231'`, while `format(Decimal(format(0.000099996, '#.4g')), 'f')` gives `0.0001000`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi well I was under the impression that this could MAYBE be done with an output format modifier (e.g. like `%.d4f`). i didnt find one, but i thought there might be one - that's why i asked about "a way", and not "can somebody write it for me", which was _not_ my intention. as you can see a lot of answers fit in the coments, i really did not expect to have lots of code being written here. next time I'll make that more clear and share more of my initial thoughts, can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

def format_v(v):
  precision = 4
  str_v = format(v, '.50f')    
  for i, v in enumerate(str_v[2:]):
      if v != "0":
        break
  return str_v[:i+2+precision]

def format_v_round(val):
  precision = 4
  for i, v in enumerate(format(val, '.50f')[2:]):
      if v != "0":
        break
  dot = '.'+'0'*(i+precision)
  dec = Decimal(val).quantize(Decimal(dot), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
  return format(dec, '.50f')[:2+i+precision]

for val in [0.0001234655, 0.012, 0.1, 0.00000011233]:
  print("format_v(", val, "):", format_v(val))

print("\n\n")

for val in [0.000123455, 0.000123445, 0.000123465, 0.012, 0.111155, 0.111145, 0.11115, 0.11114, 0.1, 0.00000011233]:
  print("format_v_round(", val, "):", format_v_round(val))
```

Out:

```
format_v( 0.0001234655 ): 0.0001234
format_v( 0.012 ): 0.01200
format_v( 0.1 ): 0.1000
format_v( 1.1233e-07 ): 0.0000001123

format_v_round( 0.000123455 ): 0.0001235
format_v_round( 0.000123445 ): 0.0001234
format_v_round( 0.000123465 ): 0.0001235
format_v_round( 0.012 ): 0.01200
format_v_round( 0.111155 ): 0.1112 
format_v_round( 0.111145 ): 0.1111 
format_v_round( 0.11115 ): 0.1111  
format_v_round( 0.11114 ): 0.1111  
format_v_round( 0.1 ): 0.1000
format_v_round( 1.1233e-07 ): 0.0000001123
```

Comment: This does not round.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import decimal as d
d.getcontext().prec = 10

def format_v(v):
  return round(d.Decimal(v),4)

v = 0.00001231231231
print(format_v(v))
```

Comment: I get this: `format_v(0.000122445554) -> Decimal('0.0001')`. Shouldn't that be `Decimal('0.00001231')`?

Comment: round(d.Decimal(v),4) will round off that 10 digit value to 4 position

Comment: do you try this code, how can it be wrong??

Comment: like I said - i got `Decimal("0.0001")`, which I cannot reproduce even now. see here: https://ibb.co/z8TSjbd

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, on the same line of thought of Kacper Kwaśny's answer:

```
def format_v(v):
    s=format(v, '.50f')
    return s[:6+len(list((itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x=='0', s[2:]))))]
```

But honestly, why don't you use exponential notation?

```
def format_v(v):
    s=format(v, '.50f')
    return f'{float(s):10.4e}'
```

**EDIT**

I added the conversions to string, which I had mistakenly omitted in my previous suggestions, and put hereunder a rounding version. Just to improve things a bit, this version accepts an optional `precision` argument and instead of counting the zeros in a string uses a different, more mathematical method:

```
def format_round_v(v, precision=4):
    digits=precision + abs(round(math.log(v, 10)))
    quantizer = "." + "0" * digits
    d=Decimal(v).quantize(Decimal(quantizer),ROUND_HALF_UP)
    return format(d, '.50f')[:2+digits]
```

Comment: This does not round.

Comment: Rounding was not required by OP, was it?

Comment: They did not say either way, which is why I did not vote down—yet—but best practice when displaying floating-point numbers is to round to the nearest value in the display format. This should be considered the default, and any answer should use it or at least speak to the issue.

Comment: I did not intend to lead you down the garden path, but working with floating-point arithmetic can be difficult. Trying your new code, for `0.0001234555`, it prints `0.00000011233`, which has five significant digits, rather than the four desired. using `round(math.log(v, 10))` is wrong; that switches the number of digits when the number passes about 3.16, instead of when it passes 9.9999… You want to take the floor, not round. But then there may be issues with accuracy when using log; some cases may still give the wrong value. And Mark Dickinson entered a solution that may work in the comments.